# Defining Undefined Behavior

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

Does there exist any **implementation** of C++ (and/or C) that guarantees that anytime undefined behavior is invoked, it will signal an error?  Obviously, such an implementation could not be as efficient as a standard C++ implementation, but it could be a useful debugging/testing tool.

If such an implementation does not exist, then are there any practical reasons that would make it impossible to implement?  Or is it just that no one has done the work to implement it yet?

***Edit:*** To make this a little more precise: I would like to have a compiler that allows me to make the assertion, for a *given run* of a C++ program *that ran to completion*, that no part of that run involved undefined behavior.

Comment: Valgrind detects many common cases with memory handing.

Comment: use valgrind ( and its bundled tools ) or gdb, this is your best option. C++ it's a really good language, the part about exceptions and error handling simply doesn't exist ( I can't consider a simple try-catch statement something good enough to achieve this purpose ) and it's the major flaw that you can find in the language that otherwise will be almost perfect.

Comment: Is it supposed to detect thread synchronization errors as well?  Or is it sufficient to detect all errors in single-threaded code (that runs to completion)?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mean to also include cases where "the Standard places no requirement on the implementation"? There is not the phrase "undefined behavior" in that statement, but the behavior is not defined by the Standard nontheless!

Comment: Consider these two definitions: `template<int N> struct A {}; template<int N> A<N + N> f() { } template<int N> A<N * 2> f() { }`. A program that contains these is "ill-formed; no diagnostic required" and hence *"this International Standard places no requirement on implementations with respect to that program"*. I don't know whether one can automatically compute whether two aritrary C++ expressions always yield equivalent results, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You don't have to determine that the two expressions are equivalent or not.  The One Definition Rule is defined in terms of token sequences, and they certainly are not equivalent streams of tokens.

Comment: How would you know that you have exhausted the list (which I suspect is large if not infinite) of possible "undefined behaviors" to check for?

Comment: @twalberg Surely there are fewer kinds of undefined behaviors in C++ than there are characters in the C++ standard. Hence, finite.

Comment: @PascalCuoq On the contrary, I think of the (probably infinite) universe of possible behaviors, and subtract out those codified by the standard... Still leaves a lot of possibilities...

Comment: @BenVoigt incorrect. If N * 2 and N + N will result in a different value for some N, then both of the definitions define different function templates (and the ODR won't apply). If not, for all N (as they do here), then both of the definitions define the same function template (they are said to be functionally equivalent). But if the token sequences are different (and here, they are), then they are not equivalent. The spec says if two function template declarations are functionally equivalent but not equivalent, then the program is ill-formed, and no diagnostic is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no.

I am fairly certain that for practical purposes, an implementation could make C++ a safe language, meaning every operation has well-defined behavior. Of course, this comes at a *huge* overhead and there is probably some cases where it's simply unfeasible, such as race conditions in multithreaded code.

Now, the problem is that this can't guarantee your code is defined in other implementations! That is, it could still invoke UB. For instance, observe the following code:

```
int a;
int* b;

int foo() {
  a = 5;
  b = &a;
  return 0;
}

int bar() {
  *b = a;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo() << bar() << std::endl;
}
```

According to the standard, the order that `foo` and `bar` are called is up to the implementation to decide. Now, in a safe implementation this order would have to be defined, likely being left-to-right evaluation. The problem is that evaluating right-to-left invokes UB, which wouldn't be caught until you ran it on an unsafe implementation. The safe implementation could simply compile each permutation of evaluation order or do some static analysis, but this quickly becomes unfeasible and possibly undecidable.

So in conclusion, if such an implementation existed it would give you a false sense of security.

Comment: That would be interesting: finding a way to make it formally undecidable.

Comment: If such an implementation existed, it could go the extra step and tell you that `std::cout << foo() << bar() << std::endl` invoke unspecified behavior in the order `foo()` and `bar()` are called, since the inputs of one intersect the outputs of the other. It might even go as far as telling you that one of the orders then invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pubby, In this example, you don't need to predict aliasing statically, just a lot of heavyweight instrumentation.  This is a dynamic information flow problem.  You just optimistically pick an order, and in the first operation, mark anything mutated with a label for that operation, and in the second, if any side-effects touch labelled memory, raise an error signal.

Answer (score 2):

The new C standard has an interesting list in the new Annex L with the crude title "Analyzability". It talks about UB that is so-called *critical UB*. This includes among others:

- An object is referred to outside of its lifetime (6.2.4).
- A pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced
  type
- The program attempts to modify a string literal

All of these are UB that are impossible or very hard to capture, since they usually can't be completely tested at compile time. This is due to the fact that a valid C (or C++) program is composed of several compilation units that may not know much of each other. E.g if one program passes a pointer to a string literal into a function with a `char*` parameter, or even worse, a program that casts away `const`-ness from a static variable.

Comment: I believe this question allows injection of runtime tests into the executable code.

Comment: @BenVoigt, sure, but this doesn't help much, I think, at least for C. E.g it is not foreseen to capture the signature of a function. So how could such a runtime test check if we call a function correctly?

Comment: Every function pointer deference could pass the type signature (static type of the function pointer expression) as a hidden argument.  And the address-of operator applied to a function could create a wrapper/trampoline that verifies the type before calling the actual function.  Or one could implement function pointers as indexes into a table of functions, instead of actual code addresses.

Comment: The main problem is that user inputs and [pseudo-]random factors aren't known at compile-time.

Comment: I think Annex L is a great concept, though unfortunately I think its requirements are slightly too vague to be useful.  For example, `int16_t x,y; ... x <<= 1; y+=4;` the optimal Standard-compliant code for the 6502 (which lacks an add-without-carry instruction) would add 5 to `y` if `x` was negative (a "CLC--clear carry" instruction would have been required between an unsigned left-shift and an "add", but because left-shifting a negative number is Undefined Behavior, it could be omitted there).  A compiler which could determine that `y` was never used in pointer computations...

Comment: ...could legally allow the left-shift of `x` to corrupt the value of `y` while satisfying the constraints of Annex L.  Further, Annex L suggests that implementations provide a level of trapping control which would on many platforms be very expensive to implement as described.  The cost could be reduced greatly on many platforms if trap handlers had to exit via `exit`, `longjmp`, or similar mechanism, and implementations could execute as much code before or after a trap situation as desired before processing a trap, provided the compiler honored certain explicit "causality barrier" directives.

Comment: @supercat, no I don't think that such an implementation would be conforming to Annex L. This kind of left shift would perform an out-of-bounds store according to the definition, there, which would probably better be called "out-of-bounds-modification". (Also I don't think that a 2 year old question on SO is the ideal place do discuss such things :)

Answer (score 2):

Two C interpreters that detect a large class of undefined behaviors for a large subset of sequential C  are [KCC](http://code.google.com/p/c-semantics/) 
and [Frama-C's value analysis](http://blog.frama-c.com/public/csmith.pdf). They are both used to make sure that  automatically generated, automatically reduced random C programs are appropriate to [report](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/pldi12-preprint.pdf) bugs in C compilers.

From the webpage for KCC:

> One of the main aims of this work is the ability to detect undefined
>   programs (e.g., programs that read invalid memory).

A third interpreter for a dialect of C is CompCert's interpreter mode (a [writeup](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/08/29/CompCert-gets-a-safe-interpreter-mode)). This one detects all behaviors that are undefined in the input language of the certified C compiler CompCert. The input language of CompCert is essentially C, but it renders defined some behaviors that are undefined in the standard (signed arithmetic overflow is defined as computing 2's complement results, for instance).

In truth, all three of the interpreters mentioned in this answer have had difficult choices to make in the name of pragmatism.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of defining something as "undefined behaviour" is to avoid having to detect this situation in the compiler. It is defined that way, so that compilers can be built for a wide variety of platforms and architectures, and so that the hardware and software doesn't have to have specific features "just to detect undefined behaviour". Imagine that you have a memory subsystem that can't detect whether you are writing to real memory or not - how would the compiler or runtime system detect that you have just done `somepointer = rand(); *somepointer = 42;`

You can detect SOME situations. But to require that ALL are detected, would make life very difficult.

Given the Edit in the original question: I still don't think this is plausible to achieve in C. There is so much freedom to do almost anything (making pointers to almost anything, these pointers can be converted, indexed, recalculated, and all manner of other things), and will be able to cause all manner of undefined behaviour. 
There is a list of all undefined behaviour in C [here](http://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#J.2) - it lists 186 different circumstances of undefined behaviour, ranging from a backslash as the last character of the file (likely to cause compiler error, but not defined as one) to "The comparison function called by the bsearch or qsort function returns ordering values inconsistently".

How on earth do you write a compiler to check that the function passed into bsearch or qsort is ordering values consistently? Of course, if the data passed into the comparison function is of a simple type, such as integers, then it's not that difficult, but if the data type is a complex type such as

```
struct {
    char name[20];
    char street[20];
    int age;
    char post_code[10];
};
```

and the programmer decides to sort the data based on ascending name, ascending street, descending age and ascending postcode, in that order? If that's what you want, but somehow the code got messed up and post code comparison returns some inconsistant result, things will go wrong, but it's very hard to formally inspect that case. There are lots of others that are similarly obscure and complex. Sure, YOUR code may not sort names and addresses etc, but someone will probably write somethng like that at some point or another.

Comment: I understand that it would be very difficult, and it wouldn't be a compiler you'd ever use in practice.  But I want to know whether it can be done *in principle*.  As to non-determinism and your example, I would be fine saying that your code example would signal a UB error on exactly those runs where the address somepointer is not within a range that has been allocated during the current run.

Comment: @Mats: The Standard contains language about *safely-derived* pointers that takes care of cases like that... making the code illegal even when `rand()` happens to return a pointer to a valid memory location.

Comment: @Ben: So, yes, I agree that somepointer is not a safely-derived pointer. So the compiler could mark such an access invalid, but it doesn't have to, right? I'm not aware of a single compiler that (given sufficent casts to overcome type conflicts, that is, etc) that even tries to tell me "this will probably lead to undefined memory access". And if I did sufficiently complex math to arrive at an index to an allocated section of memory, I'm pretty sure the compiler has no plans to stop me from using an index way outside the valid range [e.g. using data from outside the compiler to make index].

Comment: I have edited my reply to cover some more arguments for why you probably can't do this. Given that C++ has even more different UB types, I expect that gets even worse. And I'm sure Ben will find holes in my arguments this time too - I may not explain very well, but I think it's a worse case than "mathematically prove that a complex program is accurate".

Comment: @Mats: Oh, I agree that it's practically impossible to detect all kinds of undefined behavior.  (Your casting example still leads to *unsafely-derived* pointers fairly early in the process, I think, allowing the compiler to flag it)  It's still worthwhile to try to detect as many as possible, though.  And that would probably amount to "all instances of these kinds of errors are detected -- those other kinds over there may not be".